# strange error with plist file

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, plist

I have a plist file where I added level info. It is setup as follows: It has a dictionary called patterns, then it has an array called 1, and that array contains n items, which are all dictionaries. These items have the 3 booleans and three numbers. This is my code for reading that info:

```
    func readPlstForBlocks(){

    let levelPlist = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("level\(levelToShow)", ofType: "plist")
    let levelData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: levelPlist!) as NSDictionary!
    let patterns = levelData["patterns"] as! NSDictionary
    let firstPat = patterns["1"] as! NSArray
    for item in firstPat {
        let i = item["x"]?!.floatValue
        let j = item["y"]?!.floatValue
        let movingUpwards = item["movingUpwards"] as! Bool
        let movingSidewards = item["movingSidewards"] as! Bool
        let spinning = item["spinning"] as! Bool
        let typ = item["type"]?!.floatValue
        let type = Int16(typ!)
        let posx = CGFloat(i!)
        let posy = CGFloat(j!)
    }
}
```

Now the lines `let movingUpwards = item["movingUpwards"] as! Bool
            let movingSidewards = item["movingSidewards"] as! Bool
            let spinning = item["spinning"] as! Bool` gives me a strange error, saying that i am casting from SKNode to bool and it always fails. That totally confuses me, since I have been accessing booleans from other plist with similar code plenty of times and it seemed to work just fine, and secondly, why on earth xcode would think its SKNode? Anyone knows how to solve this?

EDIT:

I am adding the plist file photo:

[image]

Comment: Show the plist file, please. Give us some real data to play with! :)

Comment: I just added the edit with the photo :)

Comment: There is no key called `"bool1"` in there! So that's why you are failing.

Comment: no, i just used bool1 for the sake of the question, to make it more general. in my original code, I of course use real names. I will edit the question.

Comment: You showed false code??? Do not lie to Stack Overflow about what your code is. Well, I still think my answer is right. And this explains your error; `movingUpwards` is an SKNode property, so in the absence of further information, Swift assumes this _is_ an SKNode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when writing Swift code, I would recommend using Swift types as much as possible, not Objective-C types. So, where you have this:

```
let levelData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: levelPlist!) as NSDictionary!
let patterns = levelData["patterns"] as! NSDictionary
let firstPat = patterns["1"] as! NSArray
```

I would write this:

```
let levelData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: levelPlist!) as! [NSObject:AnyObject]
let patterns = levelData["patterns"] as! [NSObject:AnyObject]
let firstPat = patterns["1"] as! [[NSObject:AnyObject]]
```

Now, if we get that far without crashing, Swift knows that `firstPat` is an array *of dictionaries*, which is much more than you were telling it before. This means that `for item in firstPat` can correctly type `item` as a dictionary. And that, in turn, means that you can subscript it and extract values by key:

```
for item in firstPat {
    let i = item["x"] as! Float
    let j = item["y"] as! Float
    let movingUpwards = item["movingUpwards"] as! Bool
    // ...
}
```

None of that is "good" code; the forced casts are dangerous. In real life, you should be unwrapping / casting *safely* the whole way down. But I think this will give you a more coherent approach up front.

Comment: I'd probably use a series of optional bindings. Swift 1.2 lets you specify multiple bindings where the next one depends on the previous one. It makes for pretty compact and easy-to-read code. e.g. `if let a = NSDictionary b = a["patterns"] c = b["1"]`

Comment: @DuncanC Feel free to add another answer showing that. I wasn't trying to give him his final code; I was just trying to get him past this hurdle.